# Why does ffmpeg's conversion from mono to stereo lower the volume?

Tags: stereo, mono, ffmpeg

We start with this mono file: [`test.wav`](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1ppif8a3dbtf744/test.wav?dl=1)

In `audacity` it looks like this:

[image: mono]

Then we convert it to stereo with this command:

```
ffmpeg -i test.wav -ac 2 out.wav
```

Now it looks like this:

[image: stereo]

**Notice that the amplitude changed!**

Finally, we convert the stereo back to mono:

```
ffmpeg -i out.wav -ac 1 back.wav
```

We should get the same file from which we started. But in `audacity` we get the following picture:

[image: sine wave with different phase and amplitude from original]

The questions are:

1) Why did the amplitude change when converting to stereo?

2) Why did the amplitude not change back when converting to mono?

3) how can I make the amplitude change back when converting to mono?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

1 - It seems that FFmpeg attempts to respect a common pan law (when routing a centered mono track to a stereo track, lower the mono signal by - 3 dB on each channel of the stereo track). The goal is that the perceived loudness remains coherent.

**EDIT**

As mentioned by @Mulvya, you can use the pan filter to keep input file level untouched :

```
ffmpeg -i test.wav -af "pan=stereo|c0=c0|c1=c0" out.wav
```

**END EDIT**

2 - It seems that FFmpeg attempts to lower each of the contributing mono signals to prevent the sum to be over maximum level in the destination track.

I couldn't find a definitive description of the processes involved when using the `-ac` option, but on the [AudioChannelManipulation](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/AudioChannelManipulation) page, you can find the following sentence :

> ffmpeg integrates a default down-mix (and up-mix) system that should
>   be preferred (the -ac option) over the pan filter unless you have very
>   specific needs.

3 - For a 2 channel input to a 1 channel output, it seems that :

```
ffmpeg -i out.wav -filter:a "volume=3dB" -ac 1 back.wav
```

restores the original level. That should be used with care in the general case for the reasons mentionned above (prevent overloading).

Comment: Use `ffmpeg -i test.wav -af "pan=stereo|c0=c0|c1=c0" out.wav` for mono-to-stereo step to keep channel as-is.

Comment: I'm curious if the same happens "behind the scenes" in alsa or pulseaudio when we play mono file on a stereo sound card.

Comment: That would be another question. But this question is related to the actual player software more than the underlying OS audio architecture. When playing a mono file, some players do not apply the pan law and put the untouched mono channel to L and R output channels.

Comment: @audionuma @Gyan when converting stereo to mono, same volume lowering happens. How can we use the same `pan` filter in that case?